# Displaying image in Eclipse ADT for debugging

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bufferedimage, eclipse-adt

I am working on image processing based application in eclipse ADT for which I need to output the android processed image somewhere on my computer. I have the relevant image matrix or the bitmap of the required image while my application runs.

I know that it is possible to save BufferedImage into a file in hardDisk but even then I was unable to find any direct way to convert my image matrix into BufferedImage kind.

Comment: Show some code, maybe we can help. :-)

Comment: Actually I am not able to figure out a method where I could get the processed image display on computer screen. Hence no code. :(